# Laravel routing and NGINX Config

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

I'm trying to set up a new Laravel app using an existing NGINX config... the idea is that it would be accessible at www.my-domain.com/newapp. However, I can't seem to get the NGINX configuration working:

```
location /newapp{
    rewrite ^/newapp/(.*)?$ /newapp/public/index.php?$1 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

This just takes me to the 404 page for every route I try. Here is a sample route:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return "hello, world!";
});
```

On a whim, I tried changing the default route to use "newapp" in the path, and lo and behold - it worked!

```
Route::get('/newapp', function(){
    return "hello, world!"; // This works for some reason?
});
```

I don't understand what is going on here... It seems like the route should not include "newapp" after being rewritten. When I look at the NGINX logs, I see something like this:

```
rewritten data: "/newapp/public/index.php", args: ""
```

Which is exactly what I'd expect- why does the route seem to need "newapp", even though it's not part of the arguments passed to index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much hand-wringing, I can only conclude that this is how Laravel's routing is supposed to work. I've worked around the issue by adding "newapp" as a prefix for both the web and API routes in the application. This at least saves me the trouble of needing to add it to each route individually.